# is it possible to listen the return asset quantity of specified account?

Tags: eosio-code, eosio.token, eosio.cdt, eosio.system, eosio-cpp

is it possible to listen the return asset quantity of specified account in contract?
e.g i use contract(A) to send asset of the specified account(B) to a DEX, can i listen the return asset quantity on contract A or somewhere else?

Comment: Hm I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do.  You could use the notify listener for the transfer action then you can wait for actions of that code:action that notify your contract.

Answer (score 0):

If understand your question correctly, you are looking for a notification-handler.

Take a look at this [on_notify](https://developers.eos.io/welcome/v2.0/smart-contract-guides/payable-actions/#deposit)-example.

For multiple token-contracts to listen to, you will need multiple notification-handlers.

Comment: notification-handler can only listen the notification to self, not other account, what i need is contract A to send asset to swap DEX from account B, then listen the asset returned to account B

Comment: Ah. No, that's not possible then.